# ListView show only the first item in the list

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I search a lot for an answer and didn't find one that suit me.
I found out that when I set my layout_heigh to 500dp -> all the item shown, but when it has normal size (layout_heigh=wrap_content) then only the first item is shown.

this is my code:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Add Task"
        android:onClick="addTask" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**xml_item.xml:** this is for one item to duplicate in the listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/itemText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/doneBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Done" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyListAdapter:** a class in the main_activity that extends the ArrayAdapter class so I can put in one row both TextView and a button.

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private int layout;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout= resource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mainHolder= null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView= inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.item= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
                viewHolder.btn= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
                viewHolder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), itemArray.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                mainHolder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                mainHolder.item.setText(getItem(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView item;
            Button btn;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all! :)

Answer (score 0):

> but when it has normal size (layout_heigh=wrap_content)

It is a very bad idea using a `ListView` by giving it a `height=wrap_content`.
This forces ListView to measure a few children out of the adapter at layout time, to know how big it should be.
You can check it your self debugging the `getView()` method inside the adapter.

In your case, using a `LinearLayout` just add a top margin (50dp as the Button) to your listView and use `layout_heigh=match_parent`.
Otherwise use a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I did what you suggest and it doesn't solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your listview to take up as much room as is can considering the height of any sibling views (in this case your button). Here's how to do that with the `android:layout_weight` attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Add Task"
        android:onClick="addTask" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/myListView"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```